# SELECT FROM tabela comparar valores e inserir ou alterar

Tags: php, javascript, json, websql

Gostaria de fazer a comparação de informações vindas do PHP Json e persisti-la no WEBSQL.

Tem um momento que devo saber se a informação vinda do Mysql:
Já foi cadastrada 
Alterada
Não cadatrada

Abaixo tenho o javascript que gostaria que fizesse isto MAS não esta dando certo.

O que esta feito de errado ?

```
function verificaSincronizacao(objetoJSON) {     
    db.readTransaction(function (t) {
        t.executeSql('SELECT * FROM tbl_appramal WHERE codigo = ?', [objetoJSON.ram_codigo], function (t, data) {
        var length = data.rows.length;

            if(length > 0){// Temos o cadastro já sincronizado
                if((data.rows[0].unidade != d.ram_unidade)){//Se dados for iguais não precisa atualizar
                    Atualiza(objetoJSON);
                }
            }else{//Caso não houver length dados não cadastrados então cadatrar
                Insere(objetoJSON);
            }
        });
    });     

}
```

Comment: Não é mais fácil você deletar a informação e inserir novamente? Desta forma se ela foi cadastrada não haverá problema, se ela for alterada ela será atualizada e se ela não existir será criada.

Comment: Meu amigo não quero deletar.
Eu quero o seguinte:
1 - Se tiver já cadastrado no WEBSQL e no MYSQL não houver auteração, não faça nada.

2 - Se tiver ja cadastrado no WEBSQL e no MYSQL foi alterado, altera também no WEBSQL.

3 - Se não foi cadastrado insere.

Isto eu quero porque se ja tiver cadastrado no MYSQL e sincronizado no WEBSQL não precise ser atualizado aquilo que não foi alerado no MYSQL, entendeu meu amigo ----- Obrigado pela ajuda :)

Comment: Você conseguiu encontrar a falha no meu código ??????

Fico no aguardo :)

Comment: O que não está conseguindo fazer exatamente ?

Comment: Eu consigo pegar as informações do banco Mysql em meu serviço de hospedagem via PHP em formato JSON, e quero persistir no WEBSQL, ficando assim, Eu cadastro Guilherme | Luiz Santos | Francisco Queiroz no Mysql ai o usuário no celular clica em sincronizar e persiste no WebSQL, então em certo momento Eu faço alteração ficando assim Guilherme LOPES | Luiz Santos | Francisco Queiroz, vendo este cenário o unico cadastro a ter manutenção no sincronismo é o Guilherme pois na alteração no Mysql foi inserido Lopes, então é isto que quero fazer. Alterar Inserir nos momentos certos.

Comment: Cara isso envolve um esforço de programação que não é tão necessário... Porque você pode simplesmente inserir sempre, poupando processamento do lado do cliente, como se fosse uma sincronização completa sempre.

Comment: @KhaosDoctor o problema de inserir é que vai duplicar dados já inseridos, ou o Websql  faz como o IndexedDB que reconhece os dados já inseridos e faz o Update nos dados ?

Comment: Por este motivo sugeri que fosse primeiro realizado o delete dos dados e o insert dos mesmos. Não em transações separadas, mas sempre que você for atualizar remotamente a base, delete o registro antes e insira o mesmo registro novamente, desta forma você cobre o Update e a inserção.

Comment: @KhaosDoctor obrigado pela dica funciona perfeitamente, valeu mesmo pela dica.